# Still waiting on map

Tags: navigation, mapping, move-base, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am transitioning from simulation using stage and fake_localization to a real robot.  I am running the exact same map_server each time on the robot and move_base node with sbpl_lattice_planner off the robot (my laptop).  When I run the simulation, move_base receives the map and then everything else (robot footprint, obstacles, local plan, global plan, etc.).  But when I remove the stage_ros node and fake_localization, move_base tells me it is "Still waiting on map...".  I have tried to copy every possible message I can from simulation to the robot: all the tf's, amcl_pose, odom, particlecloud.  There are only two topics I am not sending, clock and base_scan.  But in costmap_common_params.yaml I don't request a base_scan (because I am sending a pointCloud instead), and I don't think that would hold up the map.  Should I implement my own clock?  I set the param use_sim_time to 0, so I didn't think I needed it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28915/still-waiting-on-map.../) by [jacobylarson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1886/jacobylarson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to restart any process which has been started with use_sim_time true.  All nodes latch into waiting for simulated time if use_sim_time is set or if a clock message is received.  They will not transition back to using system time.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up writing a clock that just pulls in the wall clock-time and publishes that.  It worked.  The problem might be that when I run the launch file, which just creates a move_base node and rvis, the rosparam of use_sim_time changes from 0 to true.  Maybe that is why it needs a clock?  I don't know why it changes the use_sim_time parameter and Iwould be open to suggestions on how to run move_base node and rvis without it changing.

---

Originally posted by [jacobylarson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1886/jacobylarson/) with karma: 21 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1